# UDP to RTSP server in Gstreamer

Tags: udp, gstreamer, rtsp, sdp

I have an IP camera and I want to get it's video stream by using Gstreamer and send it to udpsink, then in another network receive it and share by using RTSP server.
This is my command line in first side

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v  rtspsrc location=rtsp://example:x/media.smp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5001
```

and in another side I used both these commands.

```
./test-launch  "( udpsrc port=5001 caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)98\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H264\,\ packetization-mode\=\(string\)1\,\ profile-level-id\=\(string\)640028\,\ sprop-parameter-sets\=\(string\)\"Z2QAKKy0A8ARPyo\\\=\\\,aM4Bniw\\\=\"\,\ a-framesize\=\(string\)1920-1080\,\ a-cliprect\=\(string\)\"0\\\,0\\\,1080\\\,1920\"\,\ a-framerate\=\(string\)25.0\,\ clock-base\=\(uint\)3219500149\,\ seqnum-base\=\(uint\)57852\,\ npt-start\=\(guint64\)0\,\ play-speed\=\(double\)1\,\ play-scale\=\(double\)1\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)691379019" ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )"
```

and

```
./test-launch  "( udpsrc port=5001 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )"
```

But, I got `RTSP/1.0 503 service unavailable` error.

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Please look https://github.com/RSATom/RtspRestreamServer - it's created exactly for for this task, but much simpler, robust and flexible than using udp streaming. And it's possible add SSL encription to streams.

Comment: Thank you @RSATom. I tried to generate make file by using cmake in Ubuntu Linux but I got this error message : `None of the required 'gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0' found`. I think I need to install it but I couldn't find it.

Comment: you need https://launchpad.net/%7Ersatom/+archive/ubuntu/gst-rtsp-server-1.0

Comment: and `sudo apt install libgstrtspserver-1.0-dev`

Comment: but keep in mind it works only on Ubuntu 17

Comment: I want to run it on embedded board and its OS is linaro-1.13.1 (Ubuntu 14.0 I think).Do you (@RSATom) know another solution for relaying a UDP stream to RTSP supporting TCP/UDP/HTTP?

Comment: Ubuntu 17 is required by PPA of my modified `gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0`, and it's required only on server side. On your board you will need only part of vanilla `gstreamer-rtsp-server` - `rtspclientsink`. But of course I don't know if it available on `linaro-1.13.1` and if it compatible with latest rtsp-server versions...

Comment: Btw, latest GStreamer version has WebRTC sink. It could be another good option...

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 17 and could compile the project, but i faced with another problem, it needs rtspclientsink and I dont know how get it. @RSATom

Comment: `rtspclientsink` reside in `gstreamer-rtsp-server`. So just install it on client side, even if you don't plan run server there.

Comment: You need `libgstrtspserver-1.0-0` package i think

Comment: @RSATom I might be slow but I don't understand how your app works. so if I want to restream lets say a camera on this address: rtsp://10.0.0.1:8554/stream to rtsp://10.0.0.2:8554/restream (10.0.0.2 is the servers local ip) than how can I do this?

Comment: @LaciK, if I understand you correctly, then you will need third part, which on one side will connect to rtsp://10.0.0.1:8554/stream via RTSP PLAY, and on other side will send received packets to rtsp://10.0.0.2:8554/restream via RTSP RECORD. I'm already have implementation of that sort component, but it's closed source atm. Maybe I'll open it soon, need to think a little bit about it...

Comment: @LaciK, I've opened sources of my IpCams restreamer:  https://github.com/RSATom/IpCamBox